# Animal Shelter Management C++

Tags: c++

I am working my way through "Cracking the Coding Interview" and I came up the question(3.6) to design a data structure to manage an Animal shelter with 2 animals, Cats, and Dogs such that when we dequeue the oldest animal should be removed first (FIFO)

E.g. if the animals were taken in order C,C,D,C,C,D (C- Cat, D- Dog) and someone wants to adopt an animal there could be 3 ways either adopt D, adopt C, or adopt any(I have just implemented for any as other two are trivial). If the person chooses to adopt D the first D to come in would be chosen from the queue similarly with C. If the person has no preference either of C, D who came first can be chosen.

I implemented it as below. What all improvements can be done here? One possible way is to improve printQueue() function using 'this'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class Animal {
public:
    virtual string getClassName() = 0;

    inline int getOrder() {
        return _order;
    }

    void setOrder(int order) {
        _order = order;
    }

    int setType(string type) {
        _type = type;
    }

    inline string getType() {
        return _type;
    }

    bool Compare(Animal* animal) {
        if (this->_order > animal->_order)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
private:
    int _order;
    string _type;
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    Cat(string name) : _name(name) {
    }

    inline string getClassName() {
        return "Cat";
    }

    inline string getName() {
        return _name;
    }

private:
    string _name;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    Dog(string name) : _name(name) {
    }

    inline string getClassName() {
        return "Dog";
    }

    inline string getName() {
        return _name;
    }

private:
    string _name;
};

class AnimalQueue {
public:
    void enqueue(Animal* animal) {
        if (animal->getClassName() == "Cat") {
            Cat* d = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(animal);
            if (!d) {
                cout << "\nCasting Error";
            }
            else {
                cout << "\nEnqueued Cat";
                d->setOrder(++queueOrder);
                d->setType(animal->getClassName());
                catQueue.push(d);
            }
        }
        else{

            Dog* d = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(animal);
            if (!d) {
                cout << "\nCasting Error";
            }
            else {
                cout << "\nEnqueued Dog";
                d->setOrder(++queueOrder);
                d->setType(animal->getClassName());
                dogQueue.push(d);
            }
        }
    }
    void dequeue() {
        if (catQueue.empty()) {
            dogQueue.pop();
        }
        if (dogQueue.empty())
        {
            catQueue.pop();
        }
        //Pop with smaller timestamp
        if (catQueue.front()->Compare(dogQueue.front())) {
            dogQueue.pop();
        }
        else {
            catQueue.pop();
        }
    }

    void printQueue() {
        queue<Cat*> cQueue = this->catQueue;
        queue<Dog*> dQueue = this->dogQueue;

        cout << "\nCat Queue\n";
        while (!cQueue.empty()) {
            cout << cQueue.front()->getName() << " ";
            cout << cQueue.front()->getOrder();

            cout << endl;
            cQueue.pop();
        }

        cout << "\nDog Queue\n";
        while (!dQueue.empty()) {
            cout << dQueue.front()->getName() << " ";
            cout << dQueue.front()->getOrder();

            cout << endl;
            dQueue.pop();
        }

    }

    queue<Dog*> getDogQueue() {
        return dogQueue;
    }

    queue<Cat*> getCatQueue() {
        return catQueue;
    }

private:
    queue<Cat*> catQueue;
    queue<Dog*> dogQueue;
    int queueOrder = -1;
};

int main()
{   
    Animal* d1 = new Dog("Max"),*d2 = new Dog ("Shaun"), *d3 = new Dog("Tiger");
    Animal* c1 = new Cat("Trace"), *c2 = new Cat("Han"), *c3 = new Cat("Meow");

    AnimalQueue queue;
    queue.enqueue(d1);
    queue.enqueue(c1);
    queue.enqueue(c2);
    queue.enqueue(d2);
    queue.enqueue(d3);
    queue.enqueue(c3);

    cout << endl;
    queue.printQueue();

    cout << endl;

    queue.dequeue();
    queue.printQueue();
}
```

Comment: You also need something else for this to compile ... `string` is an undeclared identifier ...

Comment: That's why I don't use namespaces, don't know why I did it here @L.F.

Comment: Just a note: you could solve this in C++ with templates and some constexpr with much less code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To supplement the other reviews, here are some other things you might improve.

### Use `override` where appropriate

When a virtual function is being overridden, it should be marked `override` to allow catching errors at compile time.  See [C.128](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rh-override).

### Make sure all paths return a value

The `setType` routine claims it returns an `int` but it does not.  That's an error that should be addressed.

### Don't use `std::endl` if you don't really need it

The difference betweeen `std::endl` and `'\n'` is that `'\n'` just emits a newline character, while `std::endl` actually flushes the stream.  This can be time-consuming in a program with a lot of I/O and is rarely actually needed.  It's best to *only* use `std::endl` when you have some good reason to flush the stream and it's not very often needed for simple programs such as this one.  Avoiding the habit of using `std::endl` when `'\n'` will do will pay dividends in the future as you write more complex programs with more I/O and where performance needs to be maximized.

### Think carefully about object ownership

The traditional role of a shelter is to take in animals and then give them to a new owner on adoption.  This shelter seems to only do bookkeeping of the location of animals (by handling only pointers) rather than actually taking ownership of them.  What is actually a more appropriate way to express this is by the use of a [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).  See [R.20](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r20-use-unique_ptr-or-shared_ptr-to-represent-ownership)

### Think carefully about the domain and range of numbers

The `_queueOrder` increases without bound and is used to assign the `_order` of each animal.  What happens when that number wraps around?

### Use polymorphism effectively

Whenever you find yourself writing code like this:

```
if (animal->getClassName() == "Cat") {
        Cat* d = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(animal);
```

stop and question whether this is really needed.  By using `animal->getClassName()` as a sort of home-grown polymorphism, the code is made much more brittle and hard to maintain.  Here's how I'd write that using a `std::unique_ptr` instead:

```
void enqueue(std::unique_ptr<Animal> &&animal) {
    animal->setOrder(++queueOrder);
    if (typeid(*animal) == typeid(Cat)) {
        catQueue.push_back(std::move(animal));
    } else if (typeid(*animal) == typeid(Dog)) {
        dogQueue.push_back(std::move(animal));
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("This animal is not suitable for the shelter");
    }
}
```

Note that this uses true RTTI, built into the language, instead of inventing a poor imitation.  It also `throw`s an error if the passed animal is neither a cat nor a dog.  This could be handy if someone attempted to drop off a pet rhinocerous.

### Don't expose class internals

It seems to me that `getDogQueue` and `getCatQueue` are both ill-advised and unneeded.  I'd simply omit them both.

### Base destructors should be `virtual`

The destructor of a base class, including a pure virtual one like `Animal`, should be `virtual`.  Otherwise, deleting the object could lead to undefined behavior and probably memory leaks.

### Consolidate common items into a base class

Since all of the derived classes have `_name`, why not move that functionality into the base class?

### Use `const` where practical

The `getName()` function does not alter the underlying class because it returns a copy of the name. Similarly, the `getClassName()` function does not alter the class.  Both should be declared const.

### Use standard operators

Rather than the vaguely named `Compare`, better would be to simply use the standard `operator<`.  Here's how I'd write it as a member function of `Animal`:

```
bool operator<(const Animal& b) const {
    return _order < b._order;
}
```

### Use better names

Most of the names are not bad, but rather than `AnimalQueue` and `enqueue` and `dequeue`, I'd suggest giving them more usage-oriented names rather than describing the internal structure.  So perhaps `AnimalShelter`, `dropoff` and `adopt` would be more suitable.

### Think carefully about data types

If you use a `std::deque` instead of a `std::queue`, you gain access to iterators which are useful for printing as shown in the next suggestion.

### Use an `ostream &operator<<` instead of `display`

The current code has `printQueue()` function but what would make more sense and be more general purpose would be to overload an `ostream operator<<` instead.  This renders the resulting function much smaller and easier to understand:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const AnimalShelter& as) {
    out << "\nCat Queue\n";
    for (const auto& critter : as.catQueue) {
        out << *critter << '\n';
    }
    out << "\nDog Queue\n";
    for (const auto& critter : as.dogQueue) {
        out << *critter << '\n';
    }
    return out;
}
```

I also modified the base class to include `_name` as mentioned above and wrote this `friend` function of `Animal`:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Animal& a) {
    return out << a.getClassName() << ' ' << a._name << ' ' << a._order;
}
```

### Implement the problem specification completely

The description of the problem mentions that one might be able to adopt either a cat or a dog or the first available, but only the latter function has been implemented.  Here's how I wrote all three:

```
std::unique_ptr<Animal> adopt() {
    std::unique_ptr<Animal> adoptee{nullptr};
    if (catQueue.empty() && dogQueue.empty())
        return adoptee;

    if (catQueue.empty()) {
        std::swap(adoptee, dogQueue.front());
        dogQueue.pop_front();
    } else if (dogQueue.empty() || (catQueue.front() < dogQueue.front())) {
        std::swap(adoptee, catQueue.front());
        catQueue.pop_front();
    } else {
        std::swap(adoptee, dogQueue.front());
        dogQueue.pop_front();
    }
    return adoptee;
}

std::unique_ptr<Animal> adoptCat() {
    std::unique_ptr<Animal> adoptee{nullptr};
    if (!catQueue.empty()) {
        std::swap(adoptee, catQueue.front());
        catQueue.pop_front();
    }
    return adoptee;
}

std::unique_ptr<Animal> adoptDog() {
    std::unique_ptr<Animal> adoptee{nullptr};
    if (!dogQueue.empty()) {
        std::swap(adoptee, dogQueue.front());
        dogQueue.pop_front();
    }
    return adoptee;
}
```

### Results

Here is the modified `main` to exercise the revised code:

```
int main()
{   
    AnimalShelter shelter;
    shelter.dropoff(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Dog{"Max"}));
    shelter.dropoff(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Cat{"Trace"}));
    shelter.dropoff(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Cat{"Han"}));
    shelter.dropoff(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Dog{"Shaun"}));
    shelter.dropoff(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Dog{"Tiger"}));
    shelter.dropoff(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Cat{"Meow"}));
    try {
        shelter.dropoff(std::unique_ptr<Animal>(new Rhino{"Buster"}));
    } catch (std::runtime_error &err) {
        std::cout << err.what() << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << shelter << '\n';

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {   
        auto pet = shelter.adoptDog();
        if (pet) {
            std::cout << "You have adopted " << *pet << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "sorry, there are no more pets\n";
        }
        std::cout << shelter << '\n';
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {  // adopt any
        auto pet = shelter.adopt();
        if (pet) {
            std::cout << "You have adopted " << *pet << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "sorry, there are no more pets\n";
        }
        std::cout << shelter << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "Final: \n" << shelter << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for briefly explaining! I didn't know much about std::endl as I have just used it in college to break lines but this explanation is really nice! Also, I did not think of the range of int, good point! Virtual destructor, how did I miss that!

Comment: I would suggest to use `std::make_unique` instead of `std::unique_ptr(new …)` if you have C++14 or higher. Not 100% sure that it will work.

Comment: @val: You're right about `std::make_unique`.  An earlier iteration of my code didn't work with it but this one does.  One can use `std::make_unique<Cat>("Whiskers")` for a bit more succinct code.

Comment: Why is the exception not const. Main doesn't return a value. It's a better interface if AnimalShelter had separate dropoffDog() and dropoffCat() functions, as then you wouldn't need any RTTI nonsense and the use of unique_ptr's would be hidden from the user. This is essentially Java.

Comment: @James: The exception could be `const` or even `static const`.  `main`'s return value [is implicitly 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c/43558724#43558724).  I agree that avoiding RTTI would be better; other reviews have already made that point but you propose yet another way to do so.

Comment: Insisting on exact match for the class instead of allowing extension? Not very general.

Comment: I've read on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid that `typeid(*b)==typeid(B)` is not garanteed. `std::type_index` or `.hash_code()` should be used instead.

Comment: @nowox I believe you are misinterpreting what it says. While they may not return the same _instance_, they are guaranteed to return `true` from their `operator==()`. Otherwise `typeid` would be rather useless.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the suggestions given by 1201ProgramAlarm's [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/224194), I have the following suggestions.

First, your (over)use of RTTI seems overkill here.  Even dynamic polymorphism is not necessary.  A simple class is enough:

```
enum class Species { cat, dog };

struct Animal {
    Species species;
    std::string name;
};
```

(You are missing `#include <string>`)

Second, you maintain two queues.  Since this is an animal shelter, why not merge them?  You can use `vector` to accommodate for adopters that prefer a specified species.

```
std::vector<Animal> animals;
```

Third, `dequeue` returns `void`.  This is *abandonment*, not adoption.  It should return the `Animal`.  (An animal protectionist can even go further and mark the function `[[nodiscard]]`.)

Also, let `print` accept an `ostream&`, so you can print to any stream.

Here's the revised version:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

enum class Species { cat, dog };

std::string to_string(Species species)
{
    switch (species) {
    case Species::cat:
        return "cat";
    case Species::dog:
        return "dog";
    default:
        throw std::invalid_argument{"Unrecognized species"};
    }
}

struct Animal {
    Species species;
    std::string name;
};

class Shelter {
public:
    void enqueue(Animal animal)
    {
        animals.push_back(animal);
    }
    // adopt a specific species
    Animal dequeue(Species species)
    {
        auto it = std::find_if(animals.begin(), animals.end(),
                               [=](const Animal& animal) {
                                   return animal.species == species;
                               });
        if (it == animals.end())
            throw std::logic_error{"No animal to adopt"};
        Animal animal = std::move(*it);
        animals.erase(it);
        return animal;
    }
    // adopt any animal
    Animal dequeue()
    {
        if (animals.empty())
            throw std::logic_error{"No animal to adopt"};
        Animal animal = std::move(animals.front());
        animals.erase(animals.begin());
        return animal;
    }
    void print(std::ostream& os)
    {
        for (const auto& animal : animals) {
            os << animal.name << " (" << to_string(animal.species) << ")\n";
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Animal> animals;
};

int main()
{
    Shelter shelter;
    shelter.enqueue({Species::dog, "Max"});
    shelter.enqueue({Species::cat, "Trace"});
    shelter.enqueue({Species::cat, "Han"});
    shelter.enqueue({Species::dog, "Shaun"});
    shelter.enqueue({Species::dog, "Tiger"});
    shelter.enqueue({Species::cat, "Meow"});

    shelter.print(std::cout);
    std::cout << "\n";

    auto new_pet = shelter.dequeue();
    shelter.print(std::cout);
    std::cout << "\n";

    auto new_dog = shelter.dequeue(Species::dog);
    shelter.print(std::cout);
}
```

Output:

```
Max (dog)
Trace (cat)
Han (cat)
Shaun (dog)
Tiger (dog)
Meow (cat)

Trace (cat)
Han (cat)
Shaun (dog)
Tiger (dog)
Meow (cat)

Trace (cat)
Han (cat)
Tiger (dog)
Meow (cat)
```

Comment: I would note that algorithmic-wise, maintaining differentiating queues has a different complexity trade-off than maintaining a single queue. Popping a Cat off a single-queue is an O(number-animals) operation, while popping a Cat off differentiated queues is O(1).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Good point.  It seems unlikely that OP would be dealing with a lot of animals in this case, anyway :)

Comment: My first thought was "oh another 'let's use inheritance for animals' type problem, let's see how unnecessary complex it can get" and I was not disappointed. Would give +2 if I could, given that other answers already started with virtual destructors and Knuth knows what. It' also easy to maintain different queues for each species with this approach as well if that's really necessary.

Comment: @MatthieuM. If you maintain two different queues, how would you account for the case where the species doesn't matter and you just want to dequeue an animal?

Comment: @AleksandrH: You would check the head of each queue, and pop the "most ancient". This would be O(number-species).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Right, yeah, that's what I was thinking, but wouldn't that require storing some sort of timestamp info in the struct?

Comment: @AleksandrH: Similarly to what the OP is doing, you need an index (they call "queueOrder"). I would not however store it in the Animal itself, as this is metadata, and instead would store `std::pair<Order, Dog>` and `std::pair<Order, Cat>` respectively.

Answer (score 12):

First off, you should [avoid `using namespace ::std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

In `Animal`, `getOrder` and `getType` should be `const` (`int getOrder() const`).  Since they're defined within the class definition, you don't need to include the `inline` keyword.  Similarly, getters in the derived classes should be `const`.

It is rarely ever necessary to use the `this` keyword, and the places where you use `this->` to access a member variable can do without it.

`Compare` should also be `const` (and take its parameter as a `const Animal *`, and can be simplified to `return _order > animal->_order;`.

You never delete any of the memory you allocate with `new`.

You should declare a virtual destructor for `Animal` since it is used as a base class.  It isn't a direct problem here, since you never delete any of the memory you allocate, but if you'd delete Animals you dequeue, you'd still leak memory as the strings in the derived classes would not be freed.

In `AnimalQueue` you can have separate `enqueue` methods that take `Cat *` and `Dog *` parameters.  This would avoid needing to have all that code to check the type, and would work better if you have further derived classes (like "Tiger" derived from "Cat" or "Wolf" derived from "Dog").  The generic `enqueue(Animal *)` can call the proper overloaded `enqueue` after checking the result of the dynamic cast.  Something like

```
if (auto cat = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(animal))
    enqueue(cat);
else if (auto dog = dynamic_cast<Dog*>(animal))
    enqueue(dog);
else /* error handling */;
```

assuming you're using a compiler that supports the variable declarations in `if` conditional expressions.

`dequeue` has several bugs.  It will attempt to remove elements from empty containers, and could also try to access elements from empty containers.

`printQueue` should be `const`, and should use iterators to print the contents of the queues.  Since displaying the two queues has a bunch of duplicated code, make a function that will display one queue and call that for each queue you want to display.

`getDogQueue` and `getCatQueue` should be const and return const references.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to other answers: you're using `inline` a lot. Do not.

Modern compilers (almost all starting from year 2000) don't use it for optimization anyways: they are already clever enough to do so without hints when possible. These days `inline` have another meaning in some contexts (when function is defined in many translation units), but in your situation it's a simple no-op.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It would be nice if you could add some external resources or a online compiler example to back your claim.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume in 2019 that C++17 is available.

All other answers seem to be using two `queue`s, one for each type of animal, but I think it kinda defeats the purpose that the FIFO behaviour has to be on the whole set of animals. With two `queues`, the FIFO has to be implemented by an `_order` stored with the animal, which mixes the data with the algorithm. Once the animal is adopted, out of the shelter, the `_order`has no meaning, but is still part of the structure.

Using a queue, I would use a single queue of animals, which implements FIFO. (But the `deque` allows you to remove from the middle of it)

```
std::deque<Animal> _animals;
```

Now, the animal being either a cat or a dog, I would just say so

```
using Animal = std::variant<Dog,Cat>;
```

And implement each species as its own class.

```
class Cat { /* implementation*/ };
class Dog { /* implementation*/ };
```

Then, borrowing terminology from Edward's answer, I would simply implement:

```
void dropoff(Animal a) { _animals.emplace_back(std::move(a)) };
std::optional<Animal> adoptAny() {
   if(_animals.empty()) return std::nullopt;

   auto adoptee = std::move(_animals.front());
   _animals.pop_front();
   return adoptee; // NRVO
}


template<typename T>
auto adoptFirstOfType() -> std::optional<T> {
  // Find first animal of given type
  const auto adoptee_it = std::find_if(
      begin(_animals),
      end(_animals), 
      [](const Animal& a) { return a.holds_alternative<T>(); };

  // If not found, return empty optional.
  if(adoptee_it == end(_animals)) {
      return std::nullopt;
  }

   // If found, steal the right alternative, remove from queue and return
   auto adoptee = std::get<T>(std::move(*adoptee_it));
   _animals.erase(adoptee_it);
   return adoptee; //NRVO
}

auto adoptDog() { // type deduced consistently from returned expression
   return adoptFirstOfType<Dog>();
}
auto adoptCat() { // type deduced consistently from returned expression
   return adoptFirstOfType<Cat>();
}
```

Edward's main function should work fine as is, because `optional` has the same "container access" interface as `unique_ptr`.

This allows to simply drop the `_order` and `operator<` hacks from his solution. (because yes, implementing `operator<` is a hack - it makes no sense that a Dog be more than a Cat because it arrived first in the shelter)

Comment: Good answer!  I also considered the use of `std::optional` for this.  I also like to think of C++17 as everywhere by now but just this morning I was trying to compile a program on a Raspberry Pi and found that alas, the compiler was only up to C++14.  As for `operator<` being a hack, I disagree.  The **only** ordering among animals mentioned in the problem statement is time-in-shelter, so it makes sense that a standard operator would be used to express that.  And by the way as I implemented it, it would be `Cat < Dog` if the cat had arrived first.  :)

Comment: @L.F.: You seem to be right. That would take a `deque` instead of a `queue`. Correcting this.

Comment: @Edward: You're right, the logic is inverted in my answer. Correcting this

Comment: @Edward : thinking again, I think the problem is not in the `operator<`, but in the fact that the `_order` should not belong to the `Animal` class, because once the animal is out of the shelter, the `_order` matters no more. Maybe the queue(s) should instead store a `std::pair<size_t, Animal or Dog or Cat>`, and then you could define a cleaner `operator<` like `template<typename T, typename U> bool operator<(const std::pair<size_t,T>&, const std::pair<size_t,U>&)`

Comment: My single queue is bothering me, come to think of it. Adopting a specific animal implies a lookup, and I suppose `adoptAny` is not the dominating case. As such, one queue per animal type seem to be constant-time in either case, so would be the proper way to handle the problem.

Comment: I agree that `_order` doesn't really seem like it should be in `Animal`.  One way of addressing that would be to omit it from `Animal` and then then maintain a `deque` of `std::pair<Animal, int>` to store the order in the only place it has meaning.  I considered but didn't implement it that way.

Answer (score 1):

#### Design

Is a single queue acceptable, or does each animal need its own?

Multiple queues need more bookkeeping, as well as slight overhead when enqueueing an animal, or dequeueing the senior resident regardless of species.
While one *can* put the entrance-order in the animal-class, it certainly does not belong.

A single queue potentially require looking at every single animal to find one of a specific species. On the flip-side, adding additional species comes naturally.

#### Implementation

1. `::std` is not designed for wholesale inclusion. It contains myriad symbols, there is no comprehensive list, and it is always evolving. Your code might not "work" today, but tomorrow it might fail to compile, or worse silently change ist meaning.
   Read "[Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721)" for more detail.
2. You are flat-out leaking all your animals.

   As the program terminates directly afterwards, and `delete`ing them has no observable effect you depend on, that [could be a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25142157/3204551).
   That is, if it was intentional, well-explained, and not demo-code, but neither is the case.

   Consider an appropriate use of smart-pointers, specifically [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), as manual resource-management is error-prone.
3. Generally, polymorphic types should have a virtual dtor, so they can be `delete`d polymorphically.
4. The string type is set to the classname when enqueueing? Rip that out at the roots, you can use the source directly.
5. Unless you need a friendly name for presistence or display, consider fully relying on builtin RTTI instead of adding your own home-grown variant. Use `typeid` if you want exact type-matching, or `dynamic_cast` if subtypes are fair game.
6. All member-functions defined inline are automatically `inline`.
7. Avoid needlessly copying strings, that's inefficient. Prefer [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) where applicable.
8. Mark functions `noexcept` if you can.
9. Mark overrides `override` for documentation and to allow the compiler to catch mistakes.
10. `printQueue()` clears it? That violates all expectations. And anyway, it should be `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, AnimalQueue const&)`.

    You probably should move from `std::queue` to directly using `std::deque` when fixing that, [even though you can safely access the underlying container](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5877652/3204551).

Using a single shared queue ([also live on coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02fd7e7e6e92dda8)):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

class Animal {
public:
    virtual std::string_view friendlyName() noexcept = 0;
    virtual ~Animal() = default;
};

class Cat : public Animal {
    std::string _name;
public:
    Cat(std::string name) : _name(std::move(name)) {}

    std::string_view friendlyName() noexcept override { return "Cat"; }
};

class Dog : public Animal {
    std::string _name;
public:
    Dog(std::string name) : _name(std::move(name)) {}

    std::string_view friendlyName() noexcept override { return "Dog"; }
};

class Shelter {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> _queue;
public:
    template <class T = Animal>
    std::unique_ptr<T> get() noexcept {
        auto pos = std::find_if(_queue.begin(), _queue.end(), [](auto&& x){ return dynamic_cast<T*>(x.get()); });
        if (pos == _queue.end())
            return {};
        std::unique_ptr<T> r(dynamic_cast<T*>(pos->release()));
        _queue.erase(pos);
        return r;
    }

    void put(std::unique_ptr<Animal>&& a) {
        if (a)
            _queue.push_back(std::move(a));
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Shelter const& s) {
        for (auto&& x : s._queue)
            os << x->friendlyName() << ' ';
        os << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto d1 = std::make_unique<Dog>("Max");
    auto d2 = std::make_unique<Dog>("Shaun");
    auto d3 = std::make_unique<Dog>("Tiger");
    auto c1 = std::make_unique<Cat>("Trace");
    auto c2 = std::make_unique<Cat>("Han");
    auto c3 = std::make_unique<Cat>("Meow");

    Shelter shelter;
    shelter.put(std::move(d1));
    shelter.put(std::move(c1));
    shelter.put(std::move(c2));
    shelter.put(std::move(d2));
    shelter.put(std::move(d3));
    shelter.put(std::move(c3));

    std::cout << shelter;
    shelter.get();
    std::cout << shelter;
}
```

Comment: I also proposed a solution with a single queue, but it has the inconvenient of requiring a linear search for the common case :adopting an animal of a specific species. The OP's solution of multiple queues with an everincreasing 64-bit order of entry gives constant time search in every case. You're making good points otherwise.